# Maven activeProfiles are ignored?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use for Eclipse a maven settings.xml that has a 3rd-party Artifactory location from which Maven artefacts are retrieved.

We added now an own Artifactory which hosts artefacts not contained in the former Artifactory. 
We added new profiles to the settings.xml and activated them.

What happens now, if artefacts shall be retrieved that are only in the new one, the maven build fails with an artefact not found exception. 
Looking through the debug-output it seems like Maven never tries to access the new location.

As test, we deactivated the profiles of the 3rd-party Artifactory. Now the debug-log shows that Maven tries to access our Artifactory (but only if there are no other locations than ours).

Has someone an idea why the new Artifactory is ignored if the other profiles are active?

Below is my settings.xml, the upper two "ltl-*" profiles are the new ones which seems to be not used.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ltl-releases</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>ltl-releases</id>
          <url>http://134.91.18.140:8081/artifactory/releases</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>ltl-snapshots</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>ltl-snapshots</id>
          <url>http://134.91.18.140:8081/artifactory/snapshots</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>    
    <profile>
      <id>ukp-oss-releases</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>ukp-oss-releases</id>
          <url>http://zoidberg.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/artifactory/public-releases/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>ukp-oss-releases</id>
          <url>http://zoidberg.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/artifactory/public-releases/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>ukp-oss-snapshots</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>ukp-oss-snapshots</id>
          <url>http://zoidberg.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/artifactory/public-snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>ltl-releases</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>ltl-snapshots</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>ukp-oss-releases</activeProfile>
    <!-- Uncomment the following entry if you need SNAPSHOT versions. -->
    <activeProfile>ukp-oss-snapshots</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Please post `settings.xml`; it's really hard to understand what's going on from your description alone.

Comment: I added my settings.xml